# How to executed thread in distributed manner in jmeter for different task?

Tags: parallel-processing, jmeter, performance-testing

I want jmeter do the task in following way/
No of users=100
first 50 thread will do a particluar request.
next 50 thread will do the next task.

or alternative task in repeativ manner 
or any combination of this kind.

Answer (score 0):

You can user loop controller to achieve your goal , check below please :

http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Loop_Controller

Answer (score 0):

Possible ways are as below,

1. Use 2 Thread groups each containing single request and with no. of users/threads = 50
2. Use 1 Thread group with no. of users = 100 and requests are in if controller

[image]